# How do you kill a process in multi-processing with it's PID?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

```py
import multiprocessing as mp

def func():
  the code inside func
for _ in range(10)
  process = mp.Process(target=func)
  process.start()
```

So in the code written above, how would I kill each and individual process when wanted?

Comment: You're overwriting the `process` variables which keeps track of your the processes, so there is no way to kill them. You need to either save the objects in a list or get the pid before overwriting them.

Comment: @kinshukdua yeah I know I can get the PIDs of each one of them and save them in a list before overwriting them. My only question is how do you kill a process with its PID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably save the processes in a `dict` keyed by the process id (`pid` attribute) for fast lookup. Then you can call `terminate` on the `Process` instance:

```py
import multiprocessing as mp

def func():
    ...

process_dict = {}
for _ in range(10):
    process = mp.Process(target=func)
    process.start()
    process_dict[process.pid] = process
...
# Kill a process given a pid:
# This also removes the key from the dictionary:
process = process_dict.pop(pid)
process.terminate()
...
# Wait for remaining processes to end:
for process in process_dict.values():
    process.join()
```

The assumption is that the pid belongs to one of the processes that you created (otherwise the `pop` operation will raise a `KeyError` exception.

The above code assumes you are running under a platform that uses `fork` to create new processes (such as Linux) and therefore you do not need to place code that creates new processes within a `if __name__ == '__main__':` block. But you really should tag your question with the platform.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is just what I needed.